# Magento in cPanel

Tags: magento

I uploaded a magento under the public-html folder, when I visited it and wanted to make it connected to database, it did not work.

I cannot access the configuration page, only get the message

You have chosen to open

which is a: application/x-httpd-php5
from: XXXX

What should Firefox do with this file?

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

verify that your server supports php5 and apache has the mime handler application/x-httpd-php5 configured to execute php

Comment: He'll probably need to re-build apache using a custom profile, as C-Panel's "PHP With E-Commerce" doesn't include a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you had a different PHP configuration where the site previously was (CGI vs mod_PHP).

Make sure you comment/uncomment this line in your .htaccess file (as necessary)

```
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php
```

Or just run the `EasyApache` tool in WHM to re-compile PHP with proper support for whichever wrapper you are using (`suphp` etc.)